# PHP - remove everything between these two sets of strings

Tags: php, regex

I have the below piece of html which is PHP generated, I would like to be able to remove everything between these two pieces of strings  `&lt;p` and `p&gt`

```
<li class="level1 nav-2-1 first">
    <a href="http://dev.example.com/women/"><span>Women &lt;p style=&quot;color:#73bf43;display: inline-block;font-size: 10px;&quot;&gt;- NEW&lt;/p&gt;</span></a>
</li>
<li class="level1 nav-2-2">
    <a href="http://dev.example.com/men"><span>Men&lt;p style=&quot;color: #73bf43; display: inline-block; font-size: 10px;&quot;&gt;- &lt;strong&gt;NEW&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;</span></a>
</li>
```

So far I've tried variations of the below:

```
preg_replace('/&lt.*?\p&gt|\s*/', '', $_input)
```

Where `$_input` is the string of html above.

Comment: thing is, how did those get in there in the first place?

Comment: Doesn't `preg_replace('/&lt;p.*?p&gt;/', '', $_input)` work?

Comment: You can also use $_input = strip_tags(html_entity_decode($_input)) it will remove all the html tags.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner, that is a much longer story

Comment: For regex, use something like https://regex101.com/  or http://www.phpliveregex.com/ to experiment.

Comment: @Holly I always did love a good story; just as long as there's a happy ending *heh!* ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$replaced = preg_replace('/&lt;p.*?p&gt;/', '', $data);
```